# How to avoid name conflicts for two enum values with the same name in C++?

Tags: c++, enums

Enums in C++ have one major problem: You can't have one name in two different enums like this:

```
enum Browser
{
    None = 0,
    Chrome = 1,
    Firefox = 2
}

enum OS
{
    None = 0,
    XP = 1,
    Windows7 = 2
}
```

So what is the best way to handle this issue in this example?

Comment: If the enum is specific to a class, place it inside a (public section of) the class, then refer to the elements by e.g. ClassName::None and OtherClassName::None. You can also put the enums in namespaces instead. The typical way to namespace them in pure C is via prefixes to each enumerated identifier.

Comment: My question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972317/count-on-enum-c-automatic answers your question.

Comment: enum classes in C++ 11 seem to be a good attempt. But you have to cast it after applying `|`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In C++03 you can enclose `enum` inside a `struct`:

```
struct Browser
{
  enum eBrowser
  {
    None = 0,
    Chrome = 1,
    Firefox = 2
  };
};
```

In C++11 make it an `enum class`:

```
enum class Browser
{
    None = 0,
    Chrome = 1,
    Firefox = 2
};
```

In C++03 `namespace` also can be wrapped, but personally I find wrapping `struct`/`class` better because `namespace` is more broader. e.g.

```
// file1.h
namespace X
{
  enum E { OK };
}

// file2.h
namespace X
{
  enum D { OK };
}
```

Comment: Why `struct` and not `namespace`?

Comment: @Pubby, `namespace` is also ok, but I find `struct`/`class` "philosophically" more compatible with `enum class`.

Comment: @Pubby: You can specialize templates on `struct`.

Answer (score 13):

One option is to put each enum in a different namespace:

```
namespace Foo {
  enum Browser {
      None = 0,
      Chrome = 1,
      Firefox = 2
  }
}

namespace Bar {
  enum OS {
      None = 0,
      XP = 1,
      Windows7 = 2
  }
}
```

A better option, if available with your compiler, is to use C++11 [enum classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations):

```
enum class Browser { ... }
enum class OS { ... }
```

See [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum) for a discussion on enum classes.

Answer (score 3):

Either wrap them in namespaces or in classes:

```
namespace Browser {
  enum BrowserType
  {
    None = 0,
    Chrome = 1,
    Firefox = 2
  }
}

namespace OS {
   enum OSType  {
      None = 0,
      XP = 1,
      Windows7 = 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enum class` ([scoped enums](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations)) which is supported in C++11 on up. It is strongly typed and indicates that each `enum` type is different.

```
Browser::None != OS::None   

enum class Browser
{
    None = 0,
    Chrome = 1,
    Firefox = 2
}

enum class OS
{
    None = 0,
    XP = 1,
    Windows7 = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using scoped vs. unscoped enumeration? c++11 now offers scoped enumeration. An example would be:

```
enum class Browser : <type> {

};

enum class OS : <type> {

};
```

Access the enumerated types via an object of the Browser or an object of OS.