# c++ using struct enum as a parameter won't compile

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, enums

If create an enum inside a struct for readability, mentioned here
[How to avoid name conflicts for two enum values with the same name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869790/best-practices-for-enum-in-c)

*I am planning to add more enums, here and in other situations, I just wanted to know why the struct wasn't compiling. Coming from C# and Java I was hoping for a simpler syntax –*

And have the struct as the parameter to a constructor in a class, I cannot call it from the main.cpp of a console application. 
It gives me the error **no matching function for call toBarEnc::BarEnc(BarEnc::Scheme::eScheme)’ **     main.cpp

Here is the Class

```
class BarEnc {
public:
    struct Scheme
    {
      enum eScheme
      { ADJ1M2, ADJ3M6
      };
    };

    BarEnc();
    BarEnc(BarEnc::Scheme scheme);
}
```

in main.cpp
I call it

```
BarEnc barEnc = BarEnc(BarEnc::Scheme::ADJ3M6);
```

But if I change the parameter to an int in the constructor the code compiles

```
BarEnc(int scheme);
```

If I change it to the enum the code compiles

```
BarEnc(BarEnc::Scheme::eScheme scheme);
```

But when it is a struct, it does not compile. I am relative new to C++, using GCC 4.6 to compile on Linux, using 99 standard.

Is there a reason why I can't use a struct as a parameter?

Comment: What exactly do you want your constructor to do?

Comment: it needs to keep the enum value in the class, I was using struct as it was recommended because it improved readability, I was hoping for consistency

Comment: But your class does not have an enum instance. There is nothing to set.

Comment: obviously I took out the non relevant code, my question is about it not compiling

Comment: It looks like you took out some relevant code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple question: how your enum value should be converted to struct?

Simple answer: there is no way, since there is no suitable constructor.

Your struct has no members, it has only type (`enum`), so, I have no idea, what you want to do.

Comment: so why are they enclosing enums inside structs in that thread I posted, if you have to write long parameter types like BarEnc::Scheme::eScheme scheme)

Comment: @pt123 Because the linked question asked about having several enums that contain the same identifier ("None" in that case), and putting the enums inside structs added a prefix to the names. Since you don't have that problem, the solution is of no use to you.

Comment: I am planning to add more enums, here and in other situations, I just wanted to know why the struct wasn't compiling. Coming from C# and Java I was hoping for a simpler syntax

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the constructor as

```
BarEnc(BarEnc::Scheme scheme);
```

you tell the compiler that the `BarEnc` constructor takes a *structure* as argument, and so you can't pass the enumeration value as it's an enumeration and not the structure.

---

In this case there is really no use for a separate structure just to define the enumeration, you can declare it directly in the surrounding class:

```
class BarEnc {
public:
    enum eScheme {
        ADJ1M2,
        ADJ3M6
    };

    BarEnc(eShceme scheme);
};
```

Then when creating `BarEnc` objects you pass the enumeration value:

```
BarEnc barenc(BarEnc::eScheme::ADJ1M2);
```

Comment: I thought the point of using structs around enums was to improve readability as you won't confused it with another set of enums

Comment: @pt123 Well, if you're afraid of that, just fully qualify the enumeration by writing `BarEnc::eScheme::ADJ1M2` instead, so still no need to put it in an otherwise empty structure.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use a struct as parameter.
But your struct `BarEnc::Scheme` in fact has no member.

and the const value `BarEnc::Scheme::ADJ3M6` 's type is `BarEnc::Scheme::eScheme`, it cannot auto convert to a struct.

Comment: so why are they enclosing enums inside structs in that thread I posted, if you have to write long parameter types like BarEnc::Scheme::eScheme scheme)