# Avoid name collisions with enum in C (C99)

Tags: c, enums, namespaces, c99

`enum` elements' names are susceptible to overlap/collide with both other enum elements names, variable names, etc...

```
enum Fruit
{
    apple,
    orange
};
typedef enum Fruit Fruit;


enum Color
{
    red,
    orange // <-- ERROR
};
typedef enum Color Color;


char apple='a'; // <-- ERROR
```

Is there a C99 compliant solution to avoid collision other than prefixing every enum element name?

---

**Side note:** this question has already an answer for C++

[How to avoid name conflicts for two enum values with the same name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869790/best-practices-for-enum-in-c)

I'm looking for a C99 solution.

Comment: Yes, use an appropriate name like `color_orange` and `fruit_orange`. It should also avoid the confusion when reading.

Comment: Is there a [...] solution **other than prefixing every enum element name** ?

Comment: Maybe but it would likely be a bad solution, this is a good solution that helps readability too.

Comment: is there anything better readable than `Fruit f = orange;` and `Color c = orange;` ? It's tidy and no doubt than `f` is a fruit and `c` a color

Comment: Yes `Fruit fruit = FruitOrange;`. Oh and in this case `switch (fruit) {case FruitOrange: break ...}`. If there are many fruits you will be glad to prefix them. Also `f` can be for `file`, `f**ck`, and many other wrods that start with `f` `fruit` instead is simply `fruit`.

Comment: that's ugly! :-) but of course if it's the only solution I'll go with that. "**There is no solution for that**" (if true) may be an appropriate answer.

Comment: It's not ugly `Fuirt f = orange;` is ugly, why not make it `Fruit f = o;` too and shorten it more to make it prettier?

Comment: I don't understand the question entirely. Do you want to refer to different entities with the same name?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, `f` is a letter.  Why do you assume `f` must always stand for a word?  Sometimes verbosity is pointless within context, more difficult to read, and leads to typos as you already mixed up "Fuirt" with "Fruit."  When you start down the path of "do this thing because I was told it is good," you often end up in a mire, as is evidenced by the appalling state of software "development" we see these days; where all the code runs slower, is harder to read, harder to maintain, and with more bugs every year.  A million 4-line, verbose functions in a half-million 2-function files.  Yuck!

Comment: Not an answer, but an alternative ... <<const struct {
    const int apple, pear, orange;
} Fruit = { 0,1,2 };>> ....  then reference 'Fruit.orange' . Enums seem pretty awful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C, there is no solution other than prefixing the names of the enum values.

As pointed out in the OP, C++ has a number of mechanisms, of which `enum class` is probably indicated for modern code. However, in practice the result is the same: you end up prefixing the name of the enum element with the name of the enum. Arguably, `Fruit::orange` is tidier than `FruitOrange`, but really it makes little difference to my eyes.

In some parallel universe, it would be great to have a language in which you could write:

```
Fruit selected = orange;
```

and have the compiler deduce the namespace of the constant on the right-hand side.  But I don't see how that language could be C. C doesn't have namespaces in that sense, and even if it did, the type system only allows conversions; you cannot condition the syntax of the RHS of an operator based on the LHS (and I use the word syntax deliberately, because name lookup is a syntactic property in C).

Even if you did have some language hack which sometimes implictly inserted an enum namespace, you would still need the explicit prefix on any comparison, because

```
if (apple > orange)
```

does not have a context in which deduction could take place, even though the fact that enum values in C are all of type `int` does make `FruitApple` and `FruitOrange` comparable.

Comment: Would just like to add a link to an answer that complements this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231009/6197439

Comment: Some claim that `Namespace::variableName` or `Namespace.variable_name` is "prettier" or "better," without specifying a metric with which to make these subjective judgements.  A simple `Namespace_variable` does the same thing, with less typing.  `NamespaceVariable` also.  It's mainly personal preference unless extra type info can be utilized with an `enum class` or equivalent, if the language supports it.

Comment: In C++20 at least you are not forced to always use the enum-name for scoped enums - `using`allows you to bring the enum directly into scope.
Example:
`using enum Fruit;
Fruit f = orange;`