# c using enum inside struct

Tags: c, struct, enums

I would like to create `enum` and structs in `c`.
However, I need the `enum` to be inside another `struct` (to avoid duplicating the name). Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define structure as our enum namespace
typedef struct {
    typedef enum {
        Host,
        Cookie,
        Agent
    } Name;
} header_n;

typedef struct {
    header_n::Name key; // using top enum
    char value[128];
} header_t;

int main() {

    header_t header;
    header.key = header_n::Agent;

    return 0;
}
```

In fact, I want to use `struct` for my `enum` and then use that `enum` as a separate type in another structure and then call the last structure as a complete type but I get these errors:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'typedef'
     typedef enum {

error: expected expression before ':' token
     header_n::Name key; // using top enum

error: bit-field '<anonymous>' width not an integer constant
     header_n::Name key; // using top enum

error: bit-field '<anonymous>' has invalid type

error: 'header_t {aka struct <anonymous>}' has no member named 'key'
     header.key = header_n::Agent;

error: expected expression before 'header_n'
     header.key = header_n::Agent;
```

Comment: You can not create a type-name (using `typedef`) nested inside structures. All types are *global* and as such type-names must be defined in the global (file) scope. C is not C++. Please [get a couple of good beginners books to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of just guessing about syntax.

Comment: yes i know about C .... but is there any way to define enum in that structure (only on that struct scope) and then call it like up?

Comment: No it's not possible. C doesn't have nested structural scopes like that.

Comment: This code looks like C++ code.

Comment: of for what i want to do (header_t header; header.key = header_n::Agent;) what is your suggestion? it's must be a way at all for this ! i just want to hide my enum items inside a scope and avoid from duplication.... what is your suggestion?

Comment: If you want to continue to program in C, then the answer is still no. It's just not possible. Perhaps if you take some time to ask us about the *real* problem you have, the reason *why* you want to use a solution like this, then we might be able to help you with that instead. Please [read about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as well as [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create a `typdef` for the `enum` and then use that in both `struct`s?

Comment: so when you want to create new C program and you have 2 enum with same items names, what do you do?

Comment: You mean you have two different enumerations, both using the same name for one of their values? Then you have to rename one of them. Or use things like prefixes or suffixes to make the names more unique. That's the only solution to that problem.

Comment: Just stop using the typdefs. This is C.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mix C and C++ here. the `::` construct **is** C++ not C. Even if C++ is *based* on C they are indeed different languages, and any single compilation unit (source file) can use only one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simply not possible. The C language does not support it. C requires you to do all type declarations in global space. Or to be more precise: The C standard does *not* require type declarations to work in *non*-global space.

So you simply have to choose different name for them. You can emulate the namespace feature in C++ to by naming the types in a certain way to accomplish basically the same thing. Something like this:

```
typedef enum {
...
} foo_name;

typedef struct {
    foo_name name;
} foo;

typedef enum {
...
} bar_name;

typedef struct {
    bar_name name;
} bar;

typedef struct {
    bar_name name;
    foo_name name;
} foobar;
```

Comment: you mean it's not true too ? typedef struct header_n {
    enum Names {
        Host,
        Cookie,
        Agent
    };
} header_n;
i didn't get any error from this ... is it possible to build what i want using this ?

Comment: Prefixes are more straighforward than namespaces. You have `_` instead of `::` and you don't need to declare anything more than the bare necessities.

Comment: but using prefix, getting my enum names (inside items) very long

Comment: @itmanwork You can declare an enum instance inside a struct, but you cannot use typedef. So what you want to do is impossible.

Comment: The bottom line is basically this: If this feature is extremely important to you, then don't use C.

Answer (score 12):

Several things:

1. `struct`s in C are nothing more than collections of data - they have no "smarts" to them.
2. You cannot use `typedef` within a `struct` definition;
3. A `struct` definition in C does not create a new namespace;
4. C provides 4 namespaces - one for `struct`, `union`, and `enum` tags, one for `struct` and `union` members, one for statement labels, and one for *all other identifiers* (variable names, function names, typedef names, enumeration constants, etc.).  There are no user-defined namespaces, and there's no `::` scoping operator in C.

You will either have to define your enumeration types separately from the `struct` types:

```
typedef enum { Host, Cookie, Agent } Name;

typedef struct {
  Name key;
  char value[128]
} header_t;
```

*or*, use a non-typedef'd `enum` within the `struct` definition:

```
typedef struct
{
  enum key_t { Host, Cookie, Agent } key;
  char value[128];
} header_t;

int main( void )
{
  header_t header;
  header.key = Agent;
  ...
}
```

Even though we defined the type within the `header_t` type, `enum key_t` can be used outside of it; C doesn't limit the use of the `key_t` tag to *just* `header_t` (again, `struct` definitions do not create a new namespace).  So it's possible to do this:

```
typedef struct
{
  enum key_t { Host, Cookie, Agent } key;
  char value[128];
} header_t;

int main( void )
{
  header_t header;
  header.key = Agent;
  enum key_t some_other_key = Cookie;
  ...
}
```

You can leave off the `key_t` tag:

```
typedef struct
{
  enum { Host, Cookie, Agent } key;
  char value[128];
} header_t;
```

so you can't define a new instance of that enumeration type outside of the `struct`, but you can still use the enumeration constants `Host`, `Cookie`, and `Agent` after this definition and assign them to an integer object:

```
int keyval = Host;
```

Since enumeration constants share the "all other identifiers" namespace, no two `enum` types can use the same enumeration constants between them; you can't do something like

```
typedef enum { foo, bar, bletch } EnumType1;
typedef enum { bletch, foo, bar } EnumType2;
```

The compiler will complain that each of `bletch`, `foo`, and `bar` in the second `enum` definition have already been defined.  If you want to use the same names between two different enumeration types, you'll have to create unique prefixes or suffixes for them:

```
typedef enum { T1_foo, T1_bar, T1_bletch } EnumType1;
typedef enum { T2_bletch, T2_foo, T2_bar } EnumType2;
```